# Route https over vpn

Tags: vpn, routing, https

What is the command to route all https (secure web) traffic over vpn? I know how to route an IP address:

```
route add -net 200.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 dev tun0
```

I want to route any attempt to use standard https. My organization is using a man-in-the-middle attack on all secure traffic and every time I try to go to a page using https, I get a certificate warning. I want to send it through VPN, but I don't really want to send ALL traffic over the VPN.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21093/output-traffic-on-different-interfaces-based-on-destination-port

Comment: Why only secure traffic?

Comment: @Ramhound Because standard port 80 traffic works fine. Port 443 has a man-in-the-middle attack, so it needs to be sent through VPN to avoid the browser warnings.

Comment: Your non-https is still being tracked though.

Comment: @Ramhound They spy on email. They have keyloggers in place on all computers. They have spyware to see any computer screen they want at any time. They can add/remove files from the computer without notice. It is a very oppressive environment. All I want to do is avoid the "Your connection is not secure" message in the web browser.

Comment: Have your it folk properly add the malicious certificates into the OS certificate store